# Node.js Node-Crawler TypeError : undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js

I try use node-crawler project https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler

here is code is used (it's in doc)

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");
var url = require('url');

var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, result, $) {
        // $ is Cheerio by default
        //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
        $('a').each(function(index, a) {
            var toQueueUrl = $(a).attr('href');
            c.queue(toQueueUrl);
        });
    }
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue('http://joshfire.com');
```

when i run this code it's give this error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Crawler.callback (/home/app/app.js:10:9)
    at Crawler._onContent (/home/app/node_modules/crawler/lib/crawler.js:461:17)
    at Request._callback (/home/app/node_modules/crawler/lib/crawler.js:351:18)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/app/node_modules/crawler/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/crawler/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/crawler/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

node.js version i use : v0.10.37

Comment: `$` is undefined, and undefined is not a function.

Comment: @KevinB  `$` defined here https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler/blob/master/lib/crawler.js    Chris Matthieu  in this video https://youtu.be/n-k_96h8M9g  use same code and it's work , i dont know not working for me.

Comment: I understand that, but, the error you are getting is pretty clear in stating that the documentation is wrong in this case. Something, somewhere, is causing `$` to be undefined. I don't see anything wrong with your code according to the documentation.

Comment: @KevinB i dont know , i found this issue https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler/issues/43 but its did't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Update your node.js, node-crawler and try this code instead of your callback function
callback : function (error, res, done) {
  var $ = res.$;
  $('a').each(function(index, a) {
    var toQueueUrl = $(a).attr('href');
    c.queue(toQueueUrl);
  });
}
```

Comment: I had to replace `var $ = res.$;` with `var $ = res['$']`. I'm on a Mac, I don't know if it has something to do.